# Bitness confusion

Tags: web-services, iis, sharepoint

We are migrating a sharepoint farm from a traditional DC to a private cloud.

One of the forms in a site is calling some web services, both the sharepoint site and Web Service application are housed by the same IIS server. Sharepoint site and the Web Services application are having different application pool.

After migrating, one of the forms that is calling some Web Services is throwing an error about: `data connection error`. Looking at the sharepoint logs, we found that there is `http error 500` when hitting the form's URL and that we realized that hitting the WSDL from the browser is throwing the same error too.

The error in WSDL is about: `Could not load file or assembly <...> or one of its dependencies`. This error is gone if we set the application pool settings to `Enable 32 bit = true`.

However, the rendering of form is not completed because setting the WSDL application pool to 32 bit is causing to throw a `FileNotFoundException` with stack trace:

```
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, SPUserToken userToken)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl) at ...
```

We are sure that the cause of the problem here is the binary "bitness" because we are able to simulate the above exception and able to resolve in the other forms by just setting back the 32bit option to false in application pool.

We would like to seek anyone's idea on how to resolve the issue. Unfortunately, we only have the DLL of the Web Service, it will take for us a while to get some source codes so we are hoping for some solution that requires no re-compilation. Also, the source code that we are to receive is not guaranteed to produce the same DLL that is deployed to production due to the age of this legacy system turned blackbox.

For more information on the versions of softwares used:

  IIS, source: IIS 6; destination: IIS 7.5

  Sharepoint: 2007 (yes unfortunately due to alot of reasons upgrade cannot be done just yet) - source and destination are of the same version

  OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 - source and destination are of the same version

Comment: Could you talk more about the structure of the site? In other words what is the layout of the site and applications hosted on them since you mention they are using diff appPools. Is it that they are nested folders, like you have a /bin and a /forms/bin ?

Comment: Below is the structure, the reality is we have more applications but this is trimmed just to highlight the relevant apps in question:
`/WS
/WS/SUBAPP1 - using APP_POOL1, this is working with 32bit true or false
/WS/SUBAPP2 - using APP_POOL2, this is the problematic one
/SITE1 - This is a sharepoint site, with at least 2 webservices calls. One call is to /WS/SUBAPP2 that is having the problem`

Comment: To update anyone interested in this issue, we did some workaround by keeping the App Pool settings to default (ie 32bit = false), and manually transfer files (including DLL) to the compiled temporary location of IIS.